# Jquery messes up "this" in Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Im trying to delete a specific ember formset. Normally in my controller, This reffers to the controller , but after jquery script this = "p"aragraph.

Template

```
<p {{bind-attr class=id}}{{action 'getId'}}> Delete</p>
```

Javascript

```
 getId: function(){
       $( "p" ).on('click',function() {
         var Id = $( this ).attr('class');
         console.log(Id); // Returns id properly . 
         // here this reffers to "p" normally it reffers to the controller.
       });
        this.deleteSpecificFormset(Id); // "Id" is now undefined
       },

   deleteSpecificFormset: function(formCounterID){
      var oldPersonFormCount = this.get('personFormCount'); // This as json containing e.g {id:1}
      var newFormCounter = oldPersonFormCount[formCounterID -1].delete;
      this.set('personFormCount', newFormCounter);
    },
```

You can ofc offer ember related versions to that

cheers,

Kristjan

Comment: as you are in the context of `p` there so `$(this)` belongs to `p` there, how can you say that that is normally refers to the controller?

Comment: Well normally i dont jquery , so normally it's the controller which gets called by this

Comment: Of course the `Id` on your `this.deleteSpecificFormset` line is undefined. Why would you think otherwise? It's only defined within the click callback, and that particular line *isn't* within the click callback.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a function scoping issue. Try defining `Id` in the outer function, it is later available in that same context.

```
 getId: function(){
       var Id; //declare the variable outside of the context of the jQuery anonymous function scope
       $( "p" ).on('click',function() {
         Id = $( this ).attr('class');
         console.log(Id); // Returns id properly . 
         // here this reffers to "p" normally it reffers to the controller.
       )};
        this.deleteSpecificFormset(Id); // "Id" should now be defined
 }
```

Alternatively, you can hold the outer scope `this` reference in a `self` variable and call `deleteSpecificFormset` from inside the callback:

```
getId: function(){
           var self = this;
           $( "p" ).on('click',function() {
             var Id = $( this ).attr('class');
             self.deleteSpecificFormset(Id);
           )};

     }
```

Comment: outside of `context` i think you want to mention.

Comment: Well. Put a `console.log(this);` as first line in your `getId()` function and tell me what it says.

Comment: @Tomalak Class {_childContainers: Object, _subControllers: Array[1], _dependentValidationKeys: Object, isValid: false, personmodels: Class…}

Comment: @kristjan One of the properties of `this` ought to be the element you clicked ID you clicked (also check the `arguments` of the function). Just use that directly, instead of creating that superfluous (and conceptually wrong) jQuery click binding.